# JS await fetch => [object Response]

Tags: javascript

I have this issue:
An API (Blynk.cc) have 2 output posibile: TRUE or FALSE (simple text, no JSON)
When accesing https://ip:port/APIKey/isHardwareConnected I get TRUE of FALSE
When I try to get this result with:  response = await fetch(url)
the response printed is [object Response] not TRUE or FALSE.
Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response - you likely want `response.json()` or `response.text()` to get the output you want

Answer (score 1):

i could help better if their was a example ,but you can try this.
you need to run .text() function on response.

```
 fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

your answer

```
const energielive = 'http://cristianistrate.go.ro:8080/oF3rMGDvjOrWLppZfgS9pqgulWyforSn/isHardwareConnected';
      let response = await fetch(energielive).then(response => response.text());
      console.log(response);
```

Comment: const energielive='cristianistrate.go.ro:8080/oF3rMGDvjOrWLppZfgS9pqgulWyforSn/…'; let response = await fetch(energielive).then(response => response.text());